# unable to get xdebug installed apache window 7

Tags: php, apache, installation, xdebug

I'm rebuilding my development environment - not unsing wamp or xampp etc and trying to install each bit at a time. So far this is turning into a headache.
I now have Php, apache and mysql installed and now want to install xdebug.

I have gone to the wizard on the xdebug site and copied and pasted my phpinfo there. It worked but did not advise me which version to install so I've been trying different ones to see which one will work - no joy yet.

In the apache error log it states

```
Failed loading c:\wamp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.4-vc9.dll
```

In my php.ini I have the following xdebug entries:

```
zend_extension = "c:\wamp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.4-vc9.dll"

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable = true
xdebug.profiler_enable = true
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = true
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.auto_trace=1
xdebug.trace_format=1
xdebug.profiler_append=1
xdebug.collect_params=4
xdebug.collect_return=1
xdebug.trace_output_dir="c:/wamp/tmp"
xdebug.trace_output_name= %t.trace
```

my php is 5.4.3 x64
my apache is 2.4.4 x64
OS: Win 7 64bit

I have tried xdebug versions:

```
php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.4-vc9.dll 
php_xdebug-2.2.2-5.4-vc9-nts.dll
php_xdebug-2.2.2-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll
```

I'm assuming it's a compatibility option but as the wizard sort of failed I'm not sure which version to have.

How can I get this to work and also be sure which is the correct version to use

Thanks

Comment: You need to match the compiler version (vcXX) the thread safe-ness and the architecture to your php version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Success!!!

Part of problem was the path:

instead of:

```
zend_extension = "c:\wamp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.4-vc9.dll"
```

I should have:

```
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/php/ext/php_xdebug-2.2.0-5.4-vc9.dll"
```

And I changed to version:

```
php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: I had the same problem, with similar solution. In my case I needed the 32-bit extension. Nevertheless, this configuration line worked for me *without quotes and forward slashes*. But the **full path** was indeed necessary for it to work (i.e. *extension_dir* was ignored for this zend extension). Oh, and I'm on IIS7.

Comment: I didn't have the dll file at all, so I downloaded the appropriate one (with matching PHP version) from http://xdebug.org/files/ I have 5.5, so my file ended with -5.5-vc11.dll I put it in the ext folder and then updated the path in php.ini

Answer (score 3):

use http://xdebug.org/wizard.php and put it on form output from php -i

(on cmd windows php -i >output open output file with notepad and put it on form)

then press Analyze ... and follow Xdebug Wizard Instructions

Hope these Help !!